# JavaScript run a DOS command using java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime()

Tags: javascript, dos

I am trying to run a `DIR` command (on a folder stored in Source variable) which is called from JavaScript:

```
var Source = 'C:\\Test\\Files';
var CmdCommand= 'dir ' +Source+' /s /b /a-D > c:\\file.txt';
```

However, when I'm trying to run it from JavaScript, I do not get any error, but the `DIR` command does not get executed and my `c:\\file.txt` is empty:

```
ListDirectoryAndSaveItToFIle = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec(CmdCommand);
```

If I do a print of the `CmdCommand`, I get:

```
dir C:\Test\Files /s /b /a-D > c:\file.txt
```

which works just fine if I manually run it in CMD.

Any ideas about which `c:\file.txt` file is empty if i run it from JavaScript?

Comment: How are you mixing JavaScript and Java? Is this using Rhino?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't get to the Java environment from JScript on modern Windows (because duhh) and that's the only way any of this might make sense.

Comment: are you using Java+Rhino, NodeJs, or the Browser?

Comment: Yes, I am using a tool similar to Rhino. If i use a .bat file which has the DIR command and call it using ListDirectoryAndSaveItToFIle = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:/runDir.bat"); it works just fine...Just wondering what I am missing and if anybody has any advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly run `dir` at all with `Runtime.exec` because it is not a program, but a command built in to the command interpreter. You must run it via `cmd` like this:

```
cmd /c dir C:\Test\Files /s /b /a-D > c:\file.txt
```

Also, if you're embedding this JavaScript source in a Java string literal, make sure to double-escape backslashes. `\f`, for example, is a JavaScript escape for the ASCII form feed character, so it must be escaped as `\\f`, which in a Java string literal must be escaped as `\\\\f`.

Finally, make sure the permissions are correct (i.e., that you can write to the root of C:) and it should work.